# Encrypting Database login information

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

When connecting to a mySQL database, should the login information be encrypted? For example if you have this:

```
$dbuser = "test";
$dbpass = "1234";
mysql_connect("localhost", $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

can that username and password be intercepted by an attacker? If so, how can you encrypt the data so that it doesn't happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon that everything that is sent through **insecure** HTTP is potentially visible given the right means.

There already exists a solution to your problem, namely **using HTTPS** which, I think, encodes everything that's sent, using the RSA algorithm.

Oh: If the mySQL server is on the same machine (sine you're referring to it as `localhost`) I think that wouldn't be an issue. **Perhaps someone could confirm/deny that**.

**It can't hurt**, though, to use HTTPS whenever you're dealing with **sensitive data**, I think. *Even if it's on the same server.*

In addition, I think it's good practice to add **multiple layers of security**, for you can't predict when one of them will fail.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure the connnection between PHP and MySQL is safe from eavesdropping, then force a SSL connection:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", $dbuser, $dbpass, false, MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL);
```

If your question is about shared hosting and someone reading out the configuration data, then you're often out of luck. You need a professional hoster with suxec/suphp support to change file permissions to something saner.

Comment: So **that's** how you implement a secure connection in HTTP? I never looked into it.. Is it that simple?

Comment: I can change file permissions accordingly, but I don't have an ssl certificate. Is there any way to encrypt the data without ssl?

Comment: @Felipe: No, that has nothing to do with HTTP. That's just SSL encryption for the mysql socket (webserver and database server on two machines).

Comment: @Frozen: You don't need an SSL webserver certificate for encrypting the mysqld connection. If you change your file permissions on a 08/15 hoster, then the database connection script won't be readable by PHP anymore.

Comment: @Frozen: If you have your own VPS/rootserver, then forget about the file permissions. Not an issue then.

Answer (score 1):

I think what he's asking is if the login information between the code and the server should be encrypted.

As a rule of thumb, having it in a file only writable by the owner and readable only by the web server user would be most wise, but this is marginal as anybody using the same web server can read the file **unless** the server has privilege-separation.

If your MySQL server supports SSL that would encrypt the communications between your script and the MySQL server, take a look at [mysqli::ssl_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ssl-set.php) for MySQLi or the *client_flags* parameter of [mysql_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) if you're using the old MySQL functions.

Comment: Yes thats what I am asking. Also I have my own server so other people reading the file would not be a problem. What would the chmod number be for a file like this?

Answer (score 1):

The [PHPSec.org](http://phpsec.org/) consortium has a special article on

[PHP Security Guide: Databases and SQL](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/3.html)

dealing with DB connection credentials. Take a look for best practice and so.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you put that information in a different file and you include that file in your other php files with `include` statement. Make sure only you have read/write permission to that file.